# Increment value when another column is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data:

[image]

The data should start with 1 because the first value in column next composition will be null and then till value = 1 occurs in column NEXT_COMPOSITION another column should be incremented by one (so will be 2) till the next occurence of value 1 in column NEXT_COMPOSITION. Do you have any clue how to do this ? I was trying several things including windowed functions but still I've not found any solution.

So basically the data should start with 1 because the first value in column next composition will be null and then till value = 1 occurs in column NEXT_COMPOSITION another column should be incremented by one (so will be 2) till the next occurence of value 1 in column NEXT_COMPOSITION. Do you have any clue how to do this ? I was trying several things including windowed functions but still I've not found any solution.

Comment: A) Sample data as text is more useful.   B) Do you have a column with a proper sequence i.e. and identity or datetime?

Comment: ... and the desired result. ... and code you already tried.

Comment: When you [edit] your question, please remove the duplicate paragraph.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

If by chance you have a proper sequence.  In this example, I added an identity [ID].

Provided a proper sequence, the window function `sum() over()` should do the trick

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[NEXT_COMPOSITION] int)  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,NULL)
,(2,NULL)
,(3,1)
,(4,NULL)
,(5,NULL)
,(6,1)
,(7,1)
,(8,NULL)
 
Select *
      ,Desired = 1+COUNT(NEXT_COMPOSITION) over (order by id)     from @YourTable
 Order by ID
```

**Results**

```
ID  NEXT_COMPOSITION    Desired
1   NULL                1
2   NULL                1
3   1                   2
4   NULL                2
5   NULL                2
6   1                   3
7   1                   4
8   NULL                4
```

Comment: In this case, you can actually save some typing by using `COUNT(NEXT_COMPOSITION)` since you can do away the COALESCE :)

Comment: @siggemannen Even better.  Thanks for the time saving tip :)